# ASP.NET MVC 5, não consigo trazer setado quando entro em editar

Tags: asp.net, razor, binding

Tenho uma classe de atendimento e nela tenho o Usuário responsável pelo atendimento, que é um usuário do `IdentityUser`.

> Lembrando que alterei o Id do Identity de string para "Int", apenas isso.

Consigo cadastrar normalmente, porém, quando vou editar, ele lista os usuários, mas não trás setado o usuário que já está cadastrado no atendimento.

***Entidade:***

```
[Table("Atendimentos")]
public class Atendimento
{
    [Key]
    public int AtendimentoId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Responsável pelo atendimento")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Users.Select(x => new { UsuarioId = x.Id, Nome = x.Nome + " " + x.Sobrenome }), "UsuarioId", "Nome");
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("UsuarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Já tentei colocar a propriedade "UsuarioId" para "Id" penas, por o Identity usar apenas "Id", mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou passar o quarto e último parâmetro para indicar qual dos itens é para ficar ***selecionado***:

```
var items = db.Users
              .Select(x => new { UsuarioId = x.Id, Nome = x.Nome + " " + x.Sobrenome });

var id = 1; // aqui você coloca qual dos itens é para ficar selecionado

// e aqui você passar o 4 parâmetro para que os item fique selecionado
ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(items, "UsuarioId", "Nome", id);
```

---

[Esse é o exemplo dado onde o primeiro `SelectList` fica selecionado e o segundo não.](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-aspnet-mvc/)

```
//with selected value specified
var selectItems = new SelectList(brands, "BrandId", "BikeBrand", 2);

//only the items list
var selectItems = new SelectList(brands, "BrandId", "BikeBrand");
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Classe SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [How to create a DropDownList with ASP.NET MVC](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra maneira é utilizar o DropDownListFor.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UsuarioId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Usuarios, "UsuarioId", "Nome"))
```

Você fala qual propriedade do seu model deve ser utilizada para setar o valor e qual lista deve preencher os options.